# Возможен ли в русском языке переход абстрактных существительных в конкретные без изменения исходной формы типа?

Tags: фразеология, морфология, выбор-слов, ономастика

Возможен ли в русском языке переход абстрактных существительных в конкретные без изменения исходной формы типа?  Например в как в английском beauty (красота) – а beauty (красавица).

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку: 
любовь - чувство и объект,
радость - аналогично,
и т. п.

Правда, у конкретных значений такого ряда весьма ограничена сфера применения, но тем не менее.